# iOS storyboard why do some elements not appear in simulator?

Tags: ios, storyboard, constraints, ios-simulator

I have a tableview with custom cell. The layout should be like the following picture. I have one image, 2 labels and one button. 
I added constraints for setting a fixed height and with and also I added the 4 constraints for left, right, top, bottom.

[image: http://i63.tinypic.com/10nug3q.png]

The mode of the view is Any:Any

But when I run it in the simulator, only the button appears but not the other elements.

[image: http://i64.tinypic.com/34rd0zd.png]

I assume it has something to do with constraints. How can I make it look identical in the simulator than in the storyboard?

Comment: Your constraints lines are red which means there are conflicts. Please check error messages, you will find the reason.

Comment: I can see a lot of constraints there! Try wiping them all out and recreating from scratch - just the ones you need.

Comment: Thx a lot guys. It worked after I wiped them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is that you haven't set a series of correct constraints for your items in storyboard. You can check whether the constrains have conflicts with each other by checking the exist of the red lines or yellow lines(just like the red lines appearing in the first picture).
When items are set dim constrains, they will conflict with each other and not happy to appear on the screen.

If you have any deeper questions, please leave a message.